# Feature selection with genetic algorithm in R

Tags: r, data-mining, feature-selection, bioinformatics, genetic-algorithms

I'm looking for a R-package that does feature selection using a genetic optimization algorithm. I couldn't find one on CRAN and I wonder whether there is a free one. I would be very appreciative for any help.

Comment: Have you seen this page : http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Answer (score 0):

There are packages for assessing models (like caret), and for GA, like [genalg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/genalg/index.html) and [GA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/index.html); you can use them to easily build a GA for FS, just put binary vector of whether particular feature is used in model as a chromosome and some assessment of accuracy as a fitness function, done.

Still, there is a fair cause why no-one had made a package doing this: it is a straight way into overfitting, thus a *terrible* idea.

Why? Exhaustive search for a set of features on which your model will score maximally well according to some assessment scheme is likely to find just that, and in p>>n noisy data set the chance that it will be accidently also a set of relevant attributes is close to zero.

Comment: Still, I doubt it will work, unless you have tons of cases; so please proceed with caution and validate well.